# Environment not defined

Tags: miktex, document-classes

I am writing a thesis with the gatech-thesis class. This class defines an environment, `preliminary`. When I compile (in LyX or in TeXworks), I get an error that this environment is not defined. The class as a whole is clearly recognized, because the document compiles as it should when I comment out that environment.

I'm using MikTeX for Windows 8.

Comment: What version of [`gatech-thesis`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gatech-thesis) do you have? The version on CTAN is v1.7 in the `.cls` (although the README suggests a combination of v1.5 and v1.8) and *does* include the `preliminary` environment.

Comment: I actually have 1.8 (downloaded from Georgia Tech directly). My question is precisely why this environment remains unrecognized, while the rest of the class seems to be working fine.

Comment: There are a number fields that have to be completed before the class will run, obvious ones such as `\title` etc. but also things like `\approveddate`.

Comment: I should also mention that the class works fine on a Windows 7 machine, Mac OS 10.7 and 10.8 (I'm trying to help a classmate with her W8 laptop).

Comment: Since the document class is (perhaps) very particular. Please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that contains an example usage of the `preliminary` environment. It'll help speed up getting answers.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, is there some checklist of these fields? I note now that I can make them empty, why can I not omit them entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class has a number of required fields, without these it throws various errors including claiming that the `preliminary` environment is not defined.  You can almost find all the requierd fields by looking directly in the class file `gatech-thesis.cls`, but that misses that some adviser is needed too.  The following is a minimal document that will compile:

```
\documentclass{gatech-thesis}

\begin{document}
\title{Profound title}

\author{A. Student} 

\department{Department of Mathematics}

\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}

\gradyear{2013}

\approveddate{\ }

\principaladvisor{A. Fields Medallist}

\submitdate{Tomorrow}
\begin{preliminary}
  \begin{abstract}
    Test.
  \end{abstract}
\end{preliminary}
\end{document}
```

Note that e.g. `\approvedate` must actually print something (here a space), an empty argument is not enough.  I guess the class does it this way to enforce the particular rules of the Georgia Institute of Technology.